# does mvc.net validation support the concept of ValidationGroup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Coming from the asp.net background, I really appreciated the concept of 'validationGroup' when adding validation to a page.  I've been searching for a corresponding concept within mvc.net and haven't had much luck.

Is this concept available in mvc.net?  If not, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: One alternative is a technique that simply wasn't possible in ASP.NET.  Namely, multiple <form> tags, one for each "validation group".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it doesn't come with anything like that.

I blogged about a workaround a wee while back.

[ASP.NET MVC - Validation Summary with 2 Forms & 1 View](http://blog.pagedesigners.co.nz/post/1095179251/asp-net-mvc-validation-summary-with-2-forms-1-view)

The jist of the blog post:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static string ActionValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper html, string action)
        {
            string currentAction = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

            if (currentAction.ToLower() == action.ToLower())
                return html.ValidationSummary();

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
<h2>Register</h2>

<%= Html.ActionValidationSummary("Register") %>

<form method="post" id="register-form" action="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("Register")) %>">

    ... blah ...

</form>


<h2>User Login</h2>

<%= Html.ActionValidationSummary("LogIn") %>

<form method="post" id="login-form" action="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("LogIn")) %>">

    ... blah ...

</form>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Charlino's answer, and including HtmlAttributes and other ValidationSummary properties:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper html, string action, bool excludePropertyErrors, string message, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var currentAction = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        if (currentAction.ToLower() == action.ToLower())
        {
            return html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors, message, htmlAttributes);
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Charles's method was the only approach I could find that actually worked for my purposes!
(I.e. two forms on one MVC page -> without doing forms inside partials and ajax loads for the partials. This was no good for me, as I wanted to return differing result sets to be rendered outside the form div, depending on which form was submitted)

I would advise a slight modification to the Html Extension though, because you still want a validation summary to be rendered for the non-matched validation summary so that client side validation works:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper html, string action)
        {
            string currentAction = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

            if (currentAction.ToLower() == action.ToLower())
                return html.ValidationSummary();

            return new MvcHtmlString("<div class=\"validation-summary-valid\" data-valmsg-summary=\"true\"><ul><li style=\"display:none\"></li></ul></div>");
        }
    }
}
```