# MVC4 C# multiple Forms one page validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, entity-framework-4, html-helper

I've got 3 forms on one view on mvc project like this"

VIEW:

```
 <div>
        <fieldset>            
            <legend>Deposit Money</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.AccountNumber1)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select Account --")
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Amount)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Amount,new {style = "width:150px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Amount)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Comment)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(u => u.Comment,new {style = "width:250px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Comment)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value ="Clear" />

        </fieldset>

    </div>

}
</div> 
<div id="middlepanel" style="position:absolute;left:33%;right:33%;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Withdrawal", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new { })) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Deposit Failed. Check Your Details");

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Withdraw Money</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.AccountNumber1)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select Account --")
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Amount)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Amount,new {style = "width:150px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Amount)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Comment)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(u => u.Comment,new {style = "width:250px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Comment)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value ="Clear" />

        </fieldset>

    </div>

}
</div> 
<div id="rightpanel" style="position:absolute;right:0;width:33%;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Transfer", "ATM", FormMethod.Post, new { })) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true,"Deposit Failed. Check Your Details");

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Transfer Money</legend>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.AccountNumber1)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select Account --")
            </div>
            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.AccountNumber2)</div>
            <div>@Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select Account --")
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Amount)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Amount,new {style = "width:150px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Amount)
            </div>

            <div>@Html.LabelFor(u=>u.Comment)</div>
            <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(u => u.Comment,new {style = "width:250px"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Comment)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value ="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value ="Clear" />

        </fieldset>

    </div>

}
</div>
```

in my controller,  I am processing each of the above functionality.

However when one of the forms have an error (i.e blank field)
error is displayed on all the forms (validationSummary)

how can I build invidual errors per form?

Comment: See my Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924813/asp-net-mvc-4-html-beginform-in-partial-view-values-after-post-not-right/19928480#19928480

Answer (score 0):

Consider using partial views for each forms and call your partial view in your main view using

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName")
```

Comment: this tutorial will give you some basic idea about partial views, 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Comment: really sorry but it didnt help, is there any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure if you could do, this is a workaround, Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3762608/2121389) for further info, this might fix